# How to make a new window open inside main view in griffon?

Tags: model-view-controller, griffon

I use new version of griffon, 1.2.0.
Is there a way to open new window (second view) inside the main app window by clicking button or something?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the secondary View defines a top level Window container like the following

```
application(id: 'secondaryWindow', ...) { /* content */ }
```

and the application's configuration file (`Application.groovy`) contains an MVC group definition identified by 'secondary' then any controller may popup the window like this

```
import griffon.transform.Threading

class SomeController {
    @Threading(Threading.Policy.INSIDE_UITHREAD_ASYNC)
    def showSecondary = {
        def group = createMVCGroup('secondary')
        app.windowManager.show('secondaryWindow')
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, aalmiray. Thank for your quick respond. 

I tried the code above and still get error. On the first click it doesn't show the error, but for the second it's show error like this: "Can not instantiate MVC group 'window' with name 'window' because a previous instance with that name exists and was not disposed off properly".

I put your code on my main controller and the view on my second mvcGroup view. 

If I can describe it look like Groovy edit you made, but I want when I click on menu item it show me the second mvc view Window inside the main view Window.

Need your guidance.

Comment: Creating multiple instances of a particular MVC group can only done if you assign an unique id to each one of them. The example I posted does not assign an id so the mvcName is used as id. See http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/guide/applicationOverview.html#mvcGroupManager for more info on name collisions. You can't show a Window inside another Window, you can however add more components into the first Window.

Comment: Hi, aalmiray. I think i found the answer by using JInternalFrame.
Thanks for your help so far, i really appreciated. By the way, you rocks! :D